# google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeRequest.audio: object expected when I passed the object

Tags: node.js, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I tried to use google cloud speech to text in my node.js project. I followed he quick startup guides from docs. I pass a audio file in wav and flac format but in both cases I receive an error: `error TypeError: .google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeRequest.audio: object expected`

```
            try {
              const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
              const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
              const filename = require('path').join(__dirname + '/../temp/test.wav');

              const config = {
                encoding: 'LINEAR16',
                sampleRateHertz: 16000,
                languageCode: 'en-US'
              };
              const audio = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString('base64');
              const request = {
                config: config,
                audio: audio
              };
              const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
              const transcription = response.results
                .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
                .join('\n');
              console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
```

as you can see request is an object and when I consoled.log it it is properly converted toString. But the function client.recognize doesn't work. Where do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `audio` property in the `request` needs to be an object with the audioBytes as a property called `content`, like in the example below:

```
// Reads a local audio file and converts it to base64
const audioBytes = fs.readFileSync(fileName).toString('base64');

// The audio file's encoding, sample rate in hertz, and BCP-47 language code
const audio = {
  content: audioBytes,
};

const request = {
  audio: audio,
  config: config,
};
```